# Google Places API: all place details wanted

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to obtain some details on a Google Place with http-request. This is a place I'm looking at: [the place page](http://www.google.com/mapmaker?ui_type=pc&cid=9227429277586646140&src=1&continue=https://plus.google.com/106921460909830547881/about?gl=RU&hl=en-RU&utm_campaign=relatedproducts_pancake&utm_medium=website&utm_source=plus&ved=0CBEQgQY&sa=X&ei=oTcoUvfXAuLfygOOmYGgBw&gl=RU&hl=en&ep=pluspage_hover).

There is a 'Category' field there with 'Volleyball Court, ...'. But when I do a [request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyADPyA6ssXjMQ2dfpiweo-fK2MsSskp8sc&sensor=false&reference=CoQBdQAAAHQIBabFskwZ8iqPprJTzb4hxbDbaKNTECWfjRzoaTGJdwIRNyCBBrevHL54FEeafriUe-4Ob7JXh84kemXohRLYQKDAXVi2PU9WA3eCvPYBY9EV3jFj2ZGS8zX4crTgjp9xbDE2MomMXyaBeUX4Qx5qzaj19UccApWbeZWx-f6rEhBE0XpK_K7MFMGA1MEVL-JOGhRqNToxOQSMgcJqJLQYWs0WVBtZlg&extensions=true) I don't see these data.

How can I obtain full detail on a place with http request? If you know non-http way to do it, please let me know anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5260) and hopefully they will eventually add support for it.